# Difference between access 2003 runtime and access 2003 LI

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

What is the difference between access 2003 runtime and access 2003 LI

regards
Anna

Comment: What is "access 2003 LI" supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

With the runtime version you cannot create or edit objects nor code.

But do go with a newer runtime than the very old 2003. They are all free to use.

Comment: What about the Li version of Access 2003? does it have any limitations?

Comment: Don't know about a Li version. There was a full version, a runtime, and some developer tools.